# Compound types, contra variance, etc. in Scala

Tags: scala, contravariance

I'm working on some fairly generic code (yet another CSV file reader) and I've run into some trouble with contravariance. I've stripped the code down to something that I think demonstrates the problem here (I copied this from my Scala worksheet):

```
def f1(x: Int)(s: String) = Try(x+s.toInt)
val f1a: Int=>String=>Try[Int] = f1 _
val r1 = f1a(3)("2")
def f2(x: String)(s: String) = Try(x.toInt+s.toInt)
val f2a: String=>String=>Try[Int] = f2 _
val r2 = f2a("3")("2")
val fs: Seq[String with Int=>String=>Try[Int]] = Seq(f1a, f2a)
val xs: Seq[Any] = Seq(3,"3")
val r3 = for {(f,x) <- fs zip xs} yield f(x)("2")
```

Last line edited to avoid irrelevant issues after @Lee and @badcook commented.
I've tried to simplify things for the reader by providing the types for the vals although of course that's not required by the compiler. Each of the expressions *r1* and *r2* evaluates to Success(5) as expected. The expression for *r3* does not compile. The error is:

```
type mismatch;  found   : x.type (with underlying type Any)  required: String with Int
```

The problem essentially lies with the type of *x*, the parameter of *f(x)* in the for-comprehension. This is a contravariant position (the argument to a function) but *xs* and *fs* are *co*variant (the element type of a *Seq*). Thus *x* has type *Any*, but *f* requires a type *String with Int*.

This is an uninhabited compound type and I have not been able to find a clean way to solve this problem. I can cast the values *f1a* and *f2a* to *Any=>Int=>String* but that's not the way we like to do things in Scala!

Comment: The problem is that `f1a` and `f2a` have different types, so in `fs` the compiler has inferred the `String with Int` parameter type for the functions in `Seq(f1a, f2a)`. What do you expect to happen if you try to pass an `Int` to `f2a` or a `String` to `f1a`?

Comment: Sorry, my attempt at simplifying the problem resulted in your comment and the answer from @badcook below. Perhaps I should re-phrase the code such that people don't get side-tracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I assume you are trying to do, the Scala compiler is saving you from one mistake. Your `for` comprehension is a Cartesian product of your elements and your functions. This means your function expecting an `Int` is going to get called once with a `String` and your function expecting a `String` is going to get called once with an `Int`.

What you probably want is to `zip` your two `Seq`s together and then `map` over the resulting pairs, applying each function to its paired element. Unfortunately, as you've noted, contravariance will prevent this from typechecking. This is fundamentally because all elements of a `Seq` must be the same type, whereas you want to preserve the fact that your elements have different types and that those types match the different types of your functions.

In short, if you want to go down this path, you're looking for *heterogeneous lists*, also known as HLists, rather than ordinary Scala collections. [shapeless has an implementation of this and provides `map` and `zip` methods to go along with it.](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) There's a bit of a learning curve there (I would recommend getting familiar with higher-rank types and how shapeless implements them) and HLists are a bit unwieldy to use compared to ordinary collections, but this will solve this particular kind of problem.

Comment: @badcook--Thanks for your answer. HLists may be the way to go. My for-comprehension was a bit of a red herring. It was just a simple, convenient way to generate the compiler problem.